# Test series for convergence $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$ should diverge. I think that, by comparing with the harmonic series as a minorant, but I can't see the inequality that leads me to this.

Comment: The general term is $\sim n^{-2/3}$ and decreases slower than an harmonic one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how did you see that it's $n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: I swallowed the $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\frac{1}{(n^2-1)^{1/3}}\geq \frac{1}{n}$$ holds when $$n^3-n^2+1\geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Use Ratio test. $a_n=n^{-2/3}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2-1}}$ $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{b_n}{a_n} \ne 0.$$

Then both the series behave alike.